# "ReferenceError: window is not defined" when compiling with r.js

Tags: javascript, requirejs, r.js

I've been using RequireJS and it works perfectly. I use a lot of "window.document" to manipulate different DOM elements, but when I try to optimize it with `r.js` i get a `ReferenceError: window is not defined` which only happens with `r.js`.

Here is a minimal example of code that reproduces the issue:

`index.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body >
<div id="commentbox">

</div>
<script data-main="code/main" src="code/require.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

`main.js`:

```
 require(["roomManager"], function (roomManager){
 return {

 }
 });
```

`roomManager.js`:

```
define(["commentManager"], function(commentManager){
    var commentHand = new commentManager.commentHand();
    commentHand.init();


    return{

    }
});
```

`commentManager.js`:

```
define([], function(){
    function commManager(getDisplayIdVariable){
        var messagebox = window.document.getElementById("commentbox");

        this.init = function(){
            messagebox.innerHTML = "hi!";
        }
    }
return{
        commentHand : commManager
}
});
```

This version works correctly without `r.js` but when I try to compile it by running `r.js main.js`. I get this:

```
var messagebox = window.document.getElementById("commentbox);


ReferenceError: window is not defined
         at new new commManager
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot just do `r.js main.js`.

For one thing, you have to specify `-o` so that `r.js` performs the optimization. (`r.js` can be used for other things.)

You also have to pass configuration to `r.js`, either in a file, or on the command line. One possibility for you would be:

```
r.js -o name=main out=built.js
```

I've tried this with the code you show in your question and I get no errors.

I strongly suggest going over [this documentation](http://requirejs.org/docs/optimization.html) for `r.js`.

Answer (score 0):

if your code is optional you can use

```
 if (typeof window !== 'undefined') { 
       // Inside browser
} 
{
  // outside browser
}
```